# JavaScript Global Variables Not Working in Function

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript global variables doesn't seem to work, and give `NaN` as a response instead of the desired effect.
What I'm trying to do is make it so 'var value = 0' starts at 0, and every .5 of a second it adds 1 to the value, hope you can see what I have done here.

```
var value = 0;
setInterval(move,500);
function move() {
    var value = value+1
    console.log(value);
    $(".html5").attr("value",value);
}
```

Comment: It's Becuase you are redeclaring ``value`` in ``move`` function. Which will overwrite the current value

Answer (score 2):

Remove variable re-deceleration in function. You can use this one.

```
  var value = 0;
  setInterval(move,500);
  function move() {
    value = value+1
    console.log(value);
    $(".html5").attr("value",value);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NaN` because

`var value = value+1` evaluates as

```
var value;
value = undefined + 1;
value = NaN;
```

To solve the issue stop re-declaring `value` again inside the function:

```js
var value = 0;
setInterval(move,500);
function move() {
    value = value+1
    console.log(value);
    $(".html5").attr("value",value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="html5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `var` in `function`, it creates another variable in `function scope` where the statement will be interpreted as follows;

```
var value;
value = value + 1;
```

As `value` is `undefined`, `undefined + 1`, evaluates to `NaN`

```js
var value = 0;
setInterval(move,500);
function move() {
    value = value+1
    console.log(value);
    //$(".html5").attr("value",value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `var value = value+1` inside `move` declares a new variabe named `value`, and `value+1` refers to that variable. Remove the `var` and it will use the global value:

```js
var value = 0;
setInterval(move,500);
function move() {
    value = value+1
    console.log(value);
    $(".html5").attr("value",value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="html5">
```